# How can I increment a level in Pandas MultiIndex?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

How can I increment all values in a specific level of a pandas multiindex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) and assign:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

df = df.set_index(['A','B'])
print (df)
     C  D  E  F
A B            
1 4  7  1  5  7
2 5  8  3  3  4
3 6  9  5  6  3

#change multiindex
new_index = list(zip(df.index.get_level_values('A'), df.index.get_level_values('B') + 1))
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index, names = df.index.names)
print (df)
     C  D  E  F
A B            
1 5  7  1  5  7
2 6  8  3  3  4
3 7  9  5  6  3
```

Another possible solution with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.B = df.B + 1
df = df.set_index(['A','B'])
print (df)
     C  D  E  F
A B            
1 5  7  1  5  7
2 6  8  3  3  4
3 7  9  5  6  3
```

Solution with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
print (df.reset_index().assign(B=lambda x: x.B+1).set_index(['A','B']))
```

**Timings**:

```
In [26]: %timeit (reset_set(df1))
1 loop, best of 3: 144 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit (assign_method(df3))
10 loops, best of 3: 161 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit (jul(df2))
1 loop, best of 3: 543 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit (tuples_method(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 581 ms per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
np.random.seed(100)
N = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(N,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
print (df)

df = df.set_index(['A','B'])
print (df)
df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()
df3 = df.copy()

def reset_set(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    df.B = df.B + 1
    return df.set_index(['A','B'])

def assign_method(df):
    df = df.reset_index().assign(B=lambda x: x.B+1).set_index(['A','B']) 
    return df   

def tuples_method(df):
    new_index = list(zip(df.index.get_level_values('A'), df.index.get_level_values('B') + 1))
    df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index, names = df.index.names)
    return df

def jul(df):
    df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x[0], x[1]+1) for x in df.index], names=df.index.names)
    return df
```

Thank you [`Jeff`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961894/how-can-i-increment-a-level-in-pandas-multiindex/40961935?noredirect=1#comment69135941_40961935) for another solution:

```
df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[1] + 1 , level=1, inplace=True)
print (df)

     C  D  E  F
A B            
1 5  7  1  5  7
2 6  8  3  3  4
3 7  9  5  6  3
```

Comment: Cool, thanks!  I find it strange that this is such a cumbersome operations.. :/

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Comment: I guess there are implementation details for performance that make it this way?

Comment: I thin first is faster as second, but I  can add timings

Comment: It is really interesting, but second solution is faster. I think because vectorized add in `Series`.

Comment: Performance actually doesn't matter in my application. I'd prefer code that's easier to read, so I'll go with your `reset_index` method

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html?highlight=set_level is the idiomatic way; will also by far be the most performant as you only set the actual level

Comment: @Jeff - thank you for comment. But for me it doesnt work - return weird output, I dont know why `np.random.seed(100)`
`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,5)), columns=list('ABCDE')).set_index(['A','B'])`
`print (df)` and then `df.index.set_levels((df.index.get_level_values('B') + 1) , level=1, inplace=True)` I try sort_index, tested `(df.index.get_level_values('B') + 1)` and I have no idea what can be problem.

Comment: use df.index.levels[1] + 1

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different way:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x[0], x[1]+1) for x in df.index], names=df.index.names)

1000 loops, best of 3: 840 µs per loop
```

For comparison:

```
new_index = list(zip(df.index.get_level_values('A'), 
df.index.get_level_values('B') + 1))
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index, names = df.index.names)

1000 loops, best of 3: 984 µs per loop
```

The reset_index method is 10 times slower.

Answer (score 1):

It can be as simple as

```
df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[0] + 1, 0, inplace=True)
```

***demo***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(A=[2, 3, 4, 5]),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
)
df
```

[image]

```
df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[0] + 1, 0, inplace=True)
df
```

[image]

Comment: `TypeError: 'FrozenList' does not support mutable operations.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using rename:

```
df.rename(lambda x: x+1,level=1)
```

And a way using map:

```
df.set_axis(df.index.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[-1]+1)))
```

Output:

```
     C  D  E  F
A B            
1 5  7  1  5  7
2 6  8  3  3  4
3 7  9  5  6  3
```